# HTML href as Google Apps Script variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm making an index that generates automatically from a Google Spreadsheet.
My script reads two columns, one with names and the other one with links. Then it generates an HTML  with all the names as `<li><a>"The name"</a></li>`.
My idea is to pass the links on the spreadsheet to the `href="   "` on each name, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my .gs and .html code, and a link to my spreadsheet (to work on it, you may have to make a copy).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fEYqPnp9SIS7I2lzeeoEP7Pui4l0dgLD6t7D9Lki9oE/edit?usp=sharing

**GS code**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Index');
  
  function readData() {
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1,spreadsheet.getLastRow(), spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    Logger.log(range);
    return range;
};

function readLinks() {
    var links = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 2,spreadsheet.getLastRow(), spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    Logger.log(links);
    return links;
};
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li id="proced"><a id="link"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
        
    <script>
    
    function getData(values) {
    values.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var x = document.getElementById("link");
    x.innerHTML += '<li><a href="">' + item[0] + '</li></a>';
    });
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).readData();
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i believe you can simply change `href="'+item[1]+'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Below is the modified code

**GS code**

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
  
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Index');
  
function readData() {
    var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues()
    Logger.log(data)
    return data
}
```

**HTML code**

```html
<script>

function getData(values) {
    var x = document.getElementById("link");
    values.forEach(function(item) {
        x.innerHTML += '<li><a href="' + item[1] + '">' + item[0] + '</li></a>';
    });
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).readData();

</script>
```

### Changes

Here are the main changes I made:

#### .gs

- Instead of getting the Names and Links separately, now the function `readData` gets the corresponding names and links all together by using [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange).
- This returns a two dimensional array like this:

  ```js
  [
    ["Google", "http://www.google.com/"],
    ["Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com/"],
    ["Twitter", "http://www.twitter.com/"],
    ["Youtube", "https://www.youtube.com"],
    ["Instagram", "http://www.instagram.com/"],
    ["Reddit", "http://www.reddit.com/"],
    ["Bing", "http://www.bing.com/"],
  ]
  ```
- This makes the script faster, but if you want to get the ranges individually then you would need to use `getRange("A1:A7")` or with your method of getting last rows etc. Then get both ranges. The best thing would be to put them together into a two-dimensional array to pass them to the HTML together, if not it complicates things too much, because you will need to construct a chain of call backs to get the names and then wait for the links and then link them up together on the client-side anyway.

#### .html

- Moved `var x = document.getElementById("link");` outside the forEach loop. This stays the same for each item so no need to reinitialize it each time.
- Changed forEach arguments to `function(item)` as you don't use the index.
- Since each item is now a one-dimensional array eg => `["Google", "http://www.google.com/"]` you can call:

  - `item[0]` => `"Google"`
  - `item[1]` => `"http://www.google.com/"`
- So the resulting forEach is:

  ```js
  values.forEach(function(item) {
      x.innerHTML += '<li><a href="' + item[1] + '">' + item[0] + '</li></a>';
  });
  ```